# How to post data through multiple partial view in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

**view:**

```
@model 
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "Controller"))
{
   @html.action("action1","controller1") //use model1
   @html.action("action2","controller2") //use model2
   @html.action("action3","controller3") //use model3
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
}
```

**Parent Model**

```
{
  public model model1{get; set;} 

  public model model2{get; set;} 

  public model model3{get; set;} 
}
```

**controller**

```
[httppost]
 public ActionResult Submit(parentmodel abc)
    {

    }
```

So my question is when I post the data the parentmodel is return as null but when I try as

```
[httppost]
public ActionResult Submit(model1 abc)
{
}
```

I get the form values in model1. Is my approach right? What should be done to get the form values in the parent model?

Comment: Can you show the action that returned the initial View?

Comment: Really hard to understand what you want exactly..

Comment: If you use `@Html.RenderPartial()` you will be able to pass through a model (usually a smaller part of your main model).  Using `@Html.Action()` embeds another action result in your view and isn't really the same as using partials.

Answer (score 1):

First of all always mention your model at top.

`@model MyMVCModels`

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Model1.Name)`

Here is the beauty, Model 1 value has to be appropriate while you are setting in your textboxes or controls.

Also the structuring of your Model's might not also be correct.

Comment: Thanx for your help with the change shown i rectified it in the partial views and it worked.Able to get the values in parent controller.

Comment: Is there any other approach a better one in terms of non sequential model binding as i have requirement were parent model should be independent with partial view model.So in this case MymvcModels is dependent on model1.It should be independent

Comment: There are 2 approaches
1. Use Jquery to post your forms - Simple and Easy.
2. You can use Ajax.
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "details-container" }))
{}
details-container -> is my div where we need to update my data.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do from your question, but if I understand it correctly, you want to pass your form values to three separate partials simultaneously?

If that's the case, I'd recommend skipping the form postback and just make three ajax calls to load the partials when you click the submit button.

Comment: Nope, Actually I want to get form values from three partial views(each having individual controller and view as shown above) in a single parent controller but the values i received are null.How to get the values in parent model?

Comment: Each three of the partial view have its own model as model1,model2 and model3.And to get the values in all model i have created parent model as above which consist above model.But the parent values are null.

Comment: @user1199036 If you just want the form values from a partial view in the parent view, you can access them through javascript just like if they were on the parent page.

Comment: Javascript is not a recommended approach